# No signature of method, although fill the same parameters grails/groovy

Tags: groovy

I had an exception. I created a service

```
def fillEmailTemplateNo1(Long profileID, String customerName, String cif, Integer soluongtaisan, String hinhthucdinhgia) {
//...
}
```

Then in a controller, I call this

```
fillEmailTemplateNo1(newProfile.id, newCustomer.customerName, newCustomer.cif, newCustomer. soLuongTaiSan, "abc")
```

Although I filled all the arguments (according to their type)), I get this exception

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static
mail.MailCollatService.fillEmailTemplateNo1() is applicable for
argument types: (java.lang.Long, java.lang.String, java.lang.String,
java.lang.Integer, java.lang.String) values: [11, 1232, 1233, 1, abc] Possible solutions:
fillEmailTemplateNo1(java.lang.Long, java.lang.String,
java.lang.String, java.lang.Integer, java.lang.String)
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling the method not on an instance but on the class (`No signature of method: **static** mail.MailCollatService.fillEmailTemplateNo1`).

So either declare it `static` in your Service (bad practise) or inject the service (just by `def mailCollatService` in an controller or another service e.g.)

Comment: I must use this service so i changed method to static, thank you